# Javascript Prototype for adding a new Function to Already Created Object

Tags: javascript

I've an object like

```
 var vehicle = {
     car:function()
     {
         console.log("Vroom");
     },
     bus:function()
     {
         console.log("Grrr");
     }
 };
```

How can I create a prototype for object vehicle to add more functions to it ?
Such that I've 1 more function called "bike" ?

Comment: Mind the difference between Javascript object literals (this is what you used above) and Javascript classes used as `var myClass = function() {...}; var myobject = new myClass()`. Only classes will use prototypes with which you could add new class members/methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "I have an object like this", do you mean that you create that object in this exact way, by using an object literal, or are you just using the object literal to describe how the object looks like?

In the first case, you can just use the solution of either RGraham or SrikanthManian.

In the second case, assuming you have an object (i.e. from an third party library) of which you don't know exactly how it was created, you could in fact manipulate the prototype of its constructor function, to make the new function available to all `vehicle` instances:

```
vehicle.constructor.prototype.bike = function () {
    console.log("bike");
};
```

The only problem with this approach is, that if `vehicle.constructor` points to `Object`, then every object will inherit this function, not only the `vehicle` objects. So the safer way might be:

```
if (vehicle.constructor !== Object) {
    vehicle.constructor.prototype.bike = function () {
        console.log("bike");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add on outside the function:

```
var vehicle = {
     car:function()
     {
         console.log("Vroom");
     },
     bus:function()
     {
         console.log("Grrr");
     }
 };
vehicle.bike = function() {
    console.log("bike");  
};
vehicle.bike();
```

Or using a prototype:

```
vehicle.constructor.prototype.bike = function() {
    console.log("bike");
};
vehicle.bike();
```

Comment: Just to know more , if I do something like vehicle.constructor.prototype.bike , will that create a prototype object which will have a single instance ?

Comment: You can't create a prototype because vehicle is a variable, not a function. SrikanthManian's answer provides a prototype version.

Comment: @RGraham yes you can, `vehicle.constructor` is a function.

Comment: @basilikum True, added this to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Dunno why you would need a prototype to add a 'bike' function when you can add it as you have done with 'car' and 'bus'.

Better approach would be:

```
 function Vehicle() {};
 Vehicle.prototype.drive = function() { //do something here};
```

Then you can create objects of type Vehicle, which will have the method 'drive'.

```
 var Car = new Vehicle();
 Car.drive();       //able to execute method added to Vehicle Prototype.
```

This could be an appropriate example of using prototype and inheritance. Hope it helps.